# How do I generate Doxygen documentation on a specific branch in a git repository

Tags: git, branch, doxygen

I have installed Doxygen and am able to successfully create html documentation on a local working directory. However, I need to create documentation for branches on the network git repository.

My question is how do I configure Doxygen to do this? I would like to have one config file that will create documentation on various branches. I'm guessing I can make use of the INPUT tag to specify different branches.

I have been working primarily with the Doxygen GUI frontend, perhaps I need to modify the config file directly. I'm new to both Doxygen and Git so any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Git to switch to the branch (`git checkout -b branch-name`). Git will then update all the files on your hard disk. Afterwards, you need to run Doxygen as you normally would.

Note: If Doxygen caches intermediate files or uses time stamps to skip "unchanged" files, this process might break. After each switch, you should tell Doxygen to do a "full" build, updating everything.

Comment: Note that Git sets the timestamp to the checkout time, so if Doxygen relies on timestamps (like all other build tools) a rebuild isn't needed

Comment: @CharlesB: Does it set the checkout time for all files (even those which didn't change) or only those that are updated?